# check if the first letter of string matches the elements of char array in c#

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in c#. I am trying to check if the first letter of postal code matches any element of char array. If it does not match any of the elements of the char array, it returns false. 
Below is the approach:

```
string firstLetter= "KLMN";
char[] postalLetters = firstLetter.ToCharArray();
string PostalCode = "N2L0G6";
bool firstPostalLetterMatch = true;

foreach(char ch in firstLetter)
{
    if (PostalCode.Substring(0, 1) != postalLetters.ToString())
    {
       firstPostalLetterMatch  = false;
    }
}

if(firstPostalLetterMatch == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Error");
}
```

for example if postal code is N2L0G6. first letter will be N. Bool should be true. Since first letter is in the char array.

Comment: Use string.contains [Miscrosoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I cannot do that because if array is char not string. so, bool firstPostalLetterMatch = postalLetters.Contains(PostalCode.Substring(0, 1)); is not valid. Bool does not have definition of contain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A. Linq

```
using System.Linq;

...

bool firstPostalLetterMatch = 
     postalLetters.Any( l => l == PostalCode[0] ); // BTW. This is case sensitive
```

This reverses the question a bit. It says: are there any letters in our collection of good letters that match the first letter of the tested postal code.

## B. `foreach`

With `foreach` you want to find any match and then you can stop looking.

```
bool firstPostalLetterMatch = false;
foreach(char ch in postalLetters)
{
   if (PostalCode[0] == ch)
   {
      firstPostalLetterMatch  = true;
      break; // Match found, we no longer have to search
   }
}
```

Comment: Indexing can't be applied directly to a string. You have to call ToCharArray() on it first. Other than that, I quite like the .Any() way. Nice and tidy and easy to read / understand.

Comment: @RossGurbutt What about [`public char this[int index] { get; }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Yep, you're right, sorry. Don't understand why it doesn't compile for me locally.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
bool firstPostalLetterMatch = false;
char postCodeFirstLetter = PostalCode.ToCharArray()[0];
foreach(char ch in firstLetter)
{
    if (postCodeFirstLetter == ch)
    {
       firstPostalLetterMatch = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I convert char array to string array and then use stringarray.contain?

Comment: A string looks like "test". Calling ToCharArray() converts it to ['t','e','s','t']. Applying [0] to this just requests the character at the first location in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're a beginner here's an easy to follow method for achieving what you need.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstLetter = "KLMN";
            int firstLength = firstLetter.Length;
            int i = 0;
            string PostalCode = "N2L0G6";
            while (i < firstLength)
            {
                if (PostalCode[0].ToString().Contains(firstLetter[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(firstLetter[i] + " matches first letter of " + PostalCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(firstLetter[i] + " does not match the first letter of " + PostalCode);
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
K does not match the first letter of N2L0G6
L does not match the first letter of N2L0G6
M does not match the first letter of N2L0G6
N matches first letter of N2L0G6
```

Comment: The spec says matches the first letter of the postcode, not any letter. 'L' should return false, not true.